# ANTLR 4 Error and Exception handling in advance before triggering listener events

Tags: java, antlr4

In ANTLR 4 error/exception handling can be extended by implementing ANTLRErrorListener. It's events will be fired only when I traverse tree which is created using lexer and parser. 
e.g.

```
parser.removeErrorListeners();
parser.addErrorListener(new MyTryDSLErrorListener());
ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
MyTryDSLListener listener = new MyTryDSLListener(); // Can be replaced by default Base listener(empty implementation)
walker.walk(listener, parser.test()); // At this line tree will be traversed and if any error then MyTryDSLErrorListener's callback will be called.
```

> I want to know if is there any clean way to get errors from input
>   string without invoking listener/visitor.

**NOTE:** *Though there is a way to handle this by replacing listener with default implementations. And then again traverse tree with own implemented listeners, like as below:*

```
walker.walk(new TryDSLBaseListener(), parser.test()); // Find if has any errors.
walker.walk(new MyTryDSLListener(), parser.test()); // Actual use case.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ANTLRErrorListener` only reports errors encountered by the Parser in-line during parsing. That is, the listener reports syntax errors encountered as a result of the Parser's execution of a grammar's start rule.

The listener has no participation with parse-tree walk operations.

**Update**

```
parser.removeErrorListeners();
parser.addErrorListener(new MyTryDSLErrorListener());
ParseTree tree = parser.test();
```

Calling `parser.test()` initiates parser execution to create the parse tree. During execution, if and as the parser encounters an error, the parser reports the error through the `ANTLRErrorListener`s registered with the parser. All such errors will have been reported when `parser.test()` returns.

At this point a parse tree has been constructed. Walking is entirely separate from tree construction. The parser registered `ANTLRErrorListener`s will not be called.

```
ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
MyTryDSLListener listener = new MyTryDSLListener();
walker.walk(listener, tree);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate _by the Parser in-line during parsing_ Or If possible can you please provide me tutorials. If I am understood it then, should  I change it to: `parser.test();` ? And then add listener and walk through tree?